# Averaging over many rows of data

Tags: shell-script, awk, grep, numeric-data

I have a file of data for `1024` time steps that looks like this:

```
1 0.240112  0.0610352 1.00659  
2 0.240112  0.0610352 1.00659
...
1024    0.237366  0.0576172 1.00189
```

I want to do two things --

1. Decrease the number of rows by a factor of N, by averaging over the values of every N rows. So, e.g., for N=16, I would be left with 1024/16=64 rows of data
2. Average over an exponentially increasing number of rows. E.g., if I want to average over every 2^N rows (from 1-2, 3-4, 5-8, 9-16, ...). In this case, I would be left with log_2(1024)=10 rows.

Can I do this using `grep`or `awk`or some such command?

Answer (score 1):

#### First task:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    N = 16;
}
{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        arr[i] += $i;   
    }
}
NR % N == 0 {
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        printf "%s ", arr[i] / N;
    }
    print "";
    delete arr;

}' input.txt
```

#### Second task:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    N = 2;
}
{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        arr[i] += $i;   
    }
}
NR % N == 0 {
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        printf "%s ", arr[i] / (N - M);
    }
    print "";
    delete arr;

    M = N;
    N *= 2;
}' input.txt
```